# JQuery click event with multiple divs with the same classes

Tags: jquery, html

Im just a beginner with JQuery. I have a short JQuery script to generate some fade effects if a click event is fired. Everything works well, but if I want to use multiple sections with the same classes the click event fires the effects in both sections. So I want to fire the click event in only one section in the same time.
What is the solution for this problem? Should I use several IDs to each section?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(".big_img").fadeToggle("slow");
        $(".bottom_header").fadeToggle("slow");
        $('.small_img').fadeToggle();
    });
    
    
    $('.button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        if ($(".button").hasClass('button_animate')) {
            $('.button').removeClass('button_animate');
        } else {
            $('.button').removeClass('button_animate');
            $(".button").addClass('button_animate');
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
.client_container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 373px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #00ACC1;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 0px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.2);
    }
    
.button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    background-color: #00838F;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 0px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
    }

.button_animate {
    margin-top: 228px;
    }
    
  .big_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }
   
.header{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    background-color: #0097A7;
    }

    p {
        margin: 47px 0 0 15px;
        }

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 73px;
    background-color: #0097A7;
    }
    
    p {
        margin: 10px 0 0 12px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="client_container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <img class="big_img" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-7.jpg">
  <div class="button button_animate"></div>
</div>

<div class="client_container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <img class="big_img" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-7.jpg">
  <div class="button button_animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use DOM navigation and selection relative to `$(this)` to fire the effects only in the section containing the clicked DIV.

Comment: This must be explained in jQuery tutorials. I don't understand why we get so many questions about it.

Comment: And there must be a hundred dupes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second click function can be reduced to [jQuery toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and this function can be inserted directly into the first event handler.

For the "bottom_header" and "small_img" there is no element with those classes in your fragment, so i commented out these lines.

So the code can be:

```
    $(".button").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault;
            $(this).toggleClass('button_animate');
            $(this).prev(".big_img").fadeToggle("slow");
            //$(".bottom_header").fadeToggle("slow");
            //$('.small_img').fadeToggle();
    });
```

To access the "big_img" I used [jQuery prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $(this).toggleClass('button_animate');
    $(this).prev(".big_img").fadeToggle("slow");
    //$(".bottom_header").fadeToggle("slow");
    //$('.small_img').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.client_container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 373px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #00ACC1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 0px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.2);
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #00838F;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 0px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
}

.button_animate {
  margin-top: 228px;
}

.big_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.header{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
  background-color: #0097A7;
}

p {
  margin: 47px 0 0 15px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 73px;
  background-color: #0097A7;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="client_container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
    <img class="big_img" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-7.jpg">
    <div class="button button_animate"></div>
</div>

<div class="client_container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
    <img class="big_img" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-7.jpg">
    <div class="button button_animate"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery `$(this)` refers to the element that your event handler was triggered from, so you can use that to select other elements relative to what you clicked on using functions like `.closest()` and `.find()`. You can also combine your two separate click handler functions into one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    $(this).closest('.client_container').find(".big_img").fadeToggle("slow");
    $(this).closest('.client_container').find(".bottom_header").fadeToggle("slow");
    $(this).closest('.client_container').find('.small_img').fadeToggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('button_animate')) {
      $(this).removeClass('button_animate');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('button_animate');
      $(this).addClass('button_animate');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.client_container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 373px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #00ACC1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 0px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.2);
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #00838F;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 0px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
}
.button_animate {
  margin-top: 228px;
}
.big_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
  background-color: #0097A7;
}
p {
  margin: 47px 0 0 15px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 73px;
  background-color: #0097A7;
}
p {
  margin: 10px 0 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="client_container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <img class="big_img" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-7.jpg">
  <div class="button button_animate"></div>
</div>

<div class="client_container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <img class="big_img" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-7.jpg">
  <div class="button button_animate"></div>
</div>
```

Be sure to checkout https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score -1):

It would make sense to change the class name of the second image,
simply copy the class then add an extra number or letter to the second class name